# How do I find matching <pre> tags using a reqular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to create a simple blog that has code inclosed in `<pre>` tags.

I want to display "read more" after the first closing `</pre>` tag is encountered, thus showing only the first code segment.

I need to display all text, HTML, code up to the first closing `</pre>` tag.

What I've come up with so far is the follow:

```
 /^(.*<\/pre>).*$/m
```

However, this matches every closing `</pre>` tag up to the last one encountered.

I thought something like the following would work:

```
 /^(.*<\/pre>{1}).*$/m
```

It of course does not.

I've been using [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/).

My solution thanks to your guys help:

```
 require 'nokogiri'

 module PostsHelper
def readMore(post)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(post.message)
    intro = doc.search("div[class='intro']")
    result = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(intro)
    result << link_to("Read More", post_path(post))
    result.to_html
end
 end
```

Basically in my editor for the blog I wrap the blog preview in div class=intro
Thus, only the intro is displayed with read more added on to it.

Comment: Ahem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [not a job for regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/128421), but for a HTML/XML parser.

Using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), this will return all `<pre>` blocks as HTML, making it easy for you to grab the one you want:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <pre><p>block 1</p></pre>
    <pre><p>block 2</p></pre>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
pre_blocks = doc.search('pre')
puts pre_blocks.map(&:to_html)
```

Which will output:

```
<pre><p>block 1</p></pre>
<pre><p>block 2</p></pre>
```

Comment: Is there a way to append html to the pre_blocks result?  For example, a "read more" link.

Comment: @Brian, "Is there a way to append html to the pre_blocks result?" Yes, there is, but I'd prefer for you to see if you can figure it out yourself first. :-) Nokogiri is really well written, and the tutorials cover what you asked, so you should be able to figure it out. You'll find that Nokogiri is a really powerful tool, both for parsing and generating XML and HTML. If you can't figure it out add a comment and I'll add some samples. Also, SO has a number of [Nokogiri questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nokogiri) asking how to do various things with Nokogiri.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture all text upto the first closing pre tag by modifying your regular expression to,

```
/^(.*?<\/pre>{1}).*$/m
```

This way you can get the matched text by,

```
text.match(regex)[1]
```

which will return only the text upto the first closing pre tag.

Comment: That's called Lazy Quantification. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification

Answer (score 1):

Reluctant matching might help in your case:

```
/^(.*?<\/pre>).*$/m
```

But it's probably not the best way to do the thing, consider using some html parser, like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org).

Comment: _Reluctant_! :) I knew it like _non greedy_ http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_16.htm

Comment: @fguillen I stumbled upon that terminology in here - http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt